# Binding to main datacontext from subcontrol

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

Let's say I have a usercontrol which displays `Family` information.

One textblock of border(which datacontext is `Father`) of this usercontrol has to display name of family.

The problem is that I have binded datacontext  in codebehind:

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

Actually this codebehind has almost 4k lines of codes, and tis is reason I can't transform it to `MVVM` at this moment.

So in the codebehind  I have so properties like `Father`, `Mother` and `FamilyName`

and I need display `FamilyName` in textblock in border which has `Father` as DataContext.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be able to do is relative ancestor binding, which is coming up in Silverlight 5. (ie: Father is a member of the DataContext, and you want to access another children of the DataContext.).

As a workaround, you can declare FamilyName as a StaticResource in your Page.Resources and then bind to the StaticResource. I'm not sure if the bindings would work correctly.

Or you don't bind the whole parent control to Father. Bind to the individual elements like `{Binding Path=Father.FirstName}`

Comment: thanks for your reply. We have some misunderstanding. There is no such Property as Family. In codebehind I have such properties as Father, and FamilyName . There are at the same level.